# how to make cross platform 3d games using modern opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, opengl-es, cross-platform

How to create games that run on windows, Linux, mac os x, android, ios, wp8 etc....
using c/c++, opengl 3 or 4 and opengl es 2.0.
any tutorials or videos on how to create cross-platform 3d games.

Comment: That is a very broad question. You should narrow it down to ask specifically about the problem you're facing when trying to make your game.

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of good OpenGL tutorials, but unfortunately it is not that easy to find a good tutorial resource for OpenGL that is not outdated...

However, I recently found a pretty good website that offer 17+ tutorials about OpenGL 3.3+. You can find it at the following address: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org

As explained in [the first lesson](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/), all tutorials can be built on Windows, Linux and Mac.

So, even if it doesn't covers all your requests, I guess it's a rather good start.

Comment: There's also http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ if you _really_ want to understand how things work at a more fundamental level. I have been using OpenGL for over 15 years and Direct3D for over a decade, and I still find myself pointing people to the diagrams on that site. The quality of the diagrams and clarity of a lot of fundamental concepts are better than a lot of print-only non-API related books I have on my shelf. For cross-platform development, you really want to learn the fundamentals rather than the implementation details of a specific API; you can do both with the right tutorials.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman It's a very interesting website, and I didn't know it yet. So thank you very much for sharing this link.